# Google Cloud SQL Failover, how to setup?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to set up a new failover to my SQL instance.

This is my second instance. I made the first one a year ago, so I don't exactly remember the procedure to create a Failover instance.

When I am creating the main instance, under

**"Backups, recovery, and high availability"  > "Availability"**

I select:

*• High availability (regional)
Automatic failover to another zone within your selected region. Recommended for production instances. Increases cost.*

Is this enough to ensure I have a failover?

I am asking because after I created the instance I see there is no failover.

While under my first instance - the old one I created a year ago - I see a MySQL failover. Like this:

```
Instance ID                       Type
- sql-old-instance                MySQL 5.6
  - sql-old-instance-failover     MySQL Failover
- sql-new-instance                MySQL 5.7
```

Why there is no Failover under the new one? Is there a different way of creating it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Failover replicas are now called [standby replicas](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#HA-configuration) and are not available until a failover event occurs.

The new failover strategy works like the old strategy, but now the data is written synchronously to the master instance disk and the standby instance disk, thus reducing the downtime in a failover event.

If you marked the option `High availability (regional)` the standby replica will be created for your Cloud SQL instance.

You can test the high availability by performing a [manual failover event](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ha#console_2) this will be started the standby instance in another zone and it will atttend all queries.

To return the traffic to the master you need to perform a second manual failover event called failback.

Comment: @ndr4 if you think that it is a good answer please mark my answer as correct and upvote to help others